# Opening https://example/text.txt wont download the file directly

Tags: html

im using this command to download a file when I click on the download button`enter code here`

`<a  href="text.txt" download>download </a>`
its working perfectly but when I go to for example website/text.txt it does not download automatically how can I make it do so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.